aws SSM-SessionManagerRunShell permission setup error
I have defined the policy for a role in aws as:
    Statement":[
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ssm:TerminateSession",
        "ssm:StartSession",
        "ssm:ResumeSession"
    ],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/S(aws:userid)-",
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/$(aws:username)-*"]
    },
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action":[
        "ssm:StartSession",
        "ssm:TerminateSession",
        "ssm:DescribeSessions",
        "ssm:GetConnectionStatus"
    ],
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"]
    },
    {
    "Action": [
        "ssm:StartSession",
        "ssm:TerminateSession",
        "ssm:SendCommand"],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource: [
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-RunShellScript",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-StartSSHSession",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/SSM-SessionManagerRunShell"]
    }
]

However, I still received a notification from aws:
"In June 2024, we communicated to you about a change to AWS Systems Manager Session Manager where users with an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policy scoped down to allow specific session documents must explicitly grant access to the SSM-SessionManagerRunShell document to start interactive shell sessions."
I already updated my policy back in June as you see I add this permission. But still got this email in beginning of October. What did I do wrong here in setting up the policy?

If you have included the documents, then everything is fine in that regard, but there's already an issue with your policy, which can be the reason for policy invalidation and receiving that email, as you see below you have an additional white space after : and the Action name.
"Action": [
        "ssm: TerminateSession",
        "ssm: StartSession",
        "ssm: ResumeSession"
    ],

This resource is also written in a wrong way:
"Resource: ["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"]

it needs to be: "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:::instance/*" (you can put it within a [], but the "" were wrong placed)
full correct permission:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:TerminateSession",
        "ssm:StartSession",
        "ssm:ResumeSession"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/S(aws:userid)-*",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/$(aws:username)-*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:StartSession",
        "ssm:TerminateSession",
        "ssm:DescribeSessions",
        "ssm:GetConnectionStatus"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ssm:StartSession",
        "ssm:TerminateSession",
        "ssm:SendCommand"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-RunShellScript",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-StartSSHSession",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
        "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/SSM-SessionManagerRunShell"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Sorry those errors were all typos in my question but not on the actual policy.
I have adjusted my question and fixed them. Could you please confirm if this policy is fine..
note: this has been like this since last 4 months, yet we got email from aws.

"Resource: [
"arn:aws:ssm:::document/AWS-RunShellScript",
"arn:aws:ssm:::document/AWS-StartSSHSession",
"arn:aws:ssm:::document/AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost",
"arn:aws:ssm:::document/SSM-SessionManagerRunShell"] . this resource is wrong defined in the new update also. there's " missed after the Resource. I think you forgot also to add * at the end of this resource "arn:aws:ssm:::session/S(aws:userid)-". if these are correct also in your policy, then you can just ignore the email. if the policy is working fine and you have no issue.
